# codeigniter controller and view not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a question about CodeIgniter and how to get some information from some tables using a controller and then have it displayed in a view

I have it working using 6 tables, but I've changed the layout of the database and the names of the tables and I can't quite work out how to change the code to have it working again and I'm hoping it will be an easy 'find' for someone to look at and give me some pointers.

It has a couple of errors of

> Message: Undefined variable: cluster_task

And then one for the date of

> Message: Undefined index:item_date

Complaining about the view, but there’s probably the way I’ve defined in the controller, and I have tried changing it about 100 times and I cant see where the error(s) are?

This is what it comes out with in browser

```
From 3 June 2015 to 5 June 2015
Date        Support Item        Ref Number      Hours       Price       Cost    
4 June 2015                                         
3 June 2015                                         
5 June 2015                                         
5 June 2015                                         
1 January 1970
```

The controller code is – there’s more but this should be the relevant part =

```
        $items = new Cluster_task();
        $items->where_in('id', $cluster_task_ids)->order_by('id', 'asc')->get();

         $cluster_task_id_count = array_count_values($cluster_task_ids);

        $dates = new List_item();
        $dates->where_in('user_list_id', $id)->where('item_date >=', $start)->where('item_date <=', $end)->order_by('cluster_task_id', 'asc')->get();
        if($items->exists()) {
           echo $data['item_count_item'] = $items->result_count();  
            $data['items'] = $items;   
            $data['dates'] = array();
            foreach($dates AS $date)
            {
              $data['dates'][$date->id] = array('item_date' => $date->item_date, 'cluster_tasks' => array());
            }  
            foreach($items AS $item)
            {
                for($count = 0; $count < $cluster_task_id_count[$item->id]; $count++)
                {
                        $data['dates'][$item->cluster_task_id]['cluster_tasks'][$item->cluster_task_id] = array(
                            'name' => $item->cluster_task_support_item
                        );
                }
            }
        }         
        $data['start'] = $start;
        $data['end'] = $end; 
        $this->cfd->build('diet/preview_claim', $data);
```

And the view code is – again, there’s more but this should be the relevant part =

```
<table class="atable">
<tr>
  <th colspan="12">From <?php echo date('j F Y', strtotime($start)) ?> to <?php echo date('j F Y', strtotime($end)) ?></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Support Item</td>
<td>Ref Number</td>
<td>Hours</td>
<td>Price</td>
<td>Cost</td>
</tr>

<?php
foreach($dates AS $date) {             
    $date = $date['item_date'];        //item_categories - name ie fruit
     echo '<td class="special_column1">'.date('j F Y',    strtotime($date)).'</td>';
foreach($date['cluster_tasks'] AS $cluster_task)    
{
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="special_column1">'.date('j F Y', strtotime($date)).'</td>';
        echo '<td class="special_column3">'.$cluster_task['name'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $name = '';
   }
}
?>
</table>
```

thanks so much for your time.

Comment: `$this->load->view();` I cant find this function

Comment: I'm using $this->cfd->build('diet/preview_claim', $data); If i take out                     foreach($items AS $item)
                {
                    for($count = 0; $count < $cluster_task_id_count[$item->id]; $count++)
                    {
                            $data['dates'][$item->cluster_task_id]['cluster_tasks'][$item->cluster_task_id] = array(
                                'name' => $item->cluster_task_support_item
                            );
                    }
                } and the corresponding view code the dates work fine.

Comment: this because your `cluster_task` and `item_date` receive nothing. Simply it means no data passing

Comment: So would you have some code that i can try to fix it? thanks

Comment: without that you getting all data as well??

Comment: I actually think it's a fundamental error of my understanding of what's going on -  $data['dates'] = array();
                    foreach($dates AS $date)
                {

Comment: I thk it's a fund error of my und of what going on - i chg to $data['dates'] = array();
                    foreach($dates AS $date)
                      { $data['dates'] = array('item_date' => $date->item_date, 'cluster_task_id' => $date->cluster_task_id);print_r($data['dates']); } gives me 1 array of data that i need to somehow link to my other table to get the name but im not sure how to do this? i think using the  foreach($items AS $item) and the for($count = 0; $count < $cluster_task_id_count[$item->id]; $count++) will help but i need to compare the cluster_task_id in both tbls? but how?

Comment: In foreach($dates AS $date){$data['dates'] = array('item_date' => $date->item_date,'cluster_task_id' => $date->cluster_task_id);
print_r($data['dates']); }
Array ( [item_date] => 2015-06-04 [cluster_task_id] => 217 ) 
Array ( [item_date] => 2015-06-03 [cluster_task_id] => 218 ) etc

But I need to get the name from cluster_tasks table based on the cluster_task_id of above in the other loop and don’t know how to do this? How do I redefine this line to do this $data['dates'][$date->cluster_task_id]['cluster_tasks'][$item->cluster_task_id] = array( 
thank you

Comment: I got it working! Just to let anyone who's interested...thanks all